# Backorders Purchase higher than stock

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have Prestashop 1.6. How do I manage this issue: **Problem with backorders when a customer orders more items than are currently in stock ?.**

Our store **allows backorders**.  We have a problem where an item will show in stock, **but if a customer orders more than the available quantity**. he is not told until after the order has been placed and paid for.

I receive emails from customers who are upset because an **item appears in stock when they add it to the cart, and when they view it in the cart.**  But immediately after payment is made, the order is placed in backorder

**Example:** we have 8 balls in stock customer places an order for 10 balls.

**My idea** is to display a message shipment in 4 days. But **I don´t know how to do it.**

I will appreciate your **Help to find the solution**

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you want to display that message but i might have a solution for you.

- Go to prestashop\themes\yourTheme\templates\checkout_partials
- open cart-detailed-product-line.tpl,

at the very bottom add:

```
{if {$product.stock_quantity} < {$product.cart_quantity}{l s='Warning: Quantity of product in your cart is out-of-stock and will take longer to be delivered.'}{/if}
```

If customer orders more than avaliable quantity they will see message like this in their cart right under the product:
[How it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBbn5.png)

Hopefully that helps!